# Does SFTP Client require protocol setups on end user machine to function?

Tags: delphi, sftp

I use Delphi and I have a backup application. Currently I use FTP or FTPS to connect to predefined FTP Servers. I do not need to do install any special protocol on End User machine.

If I want to use SFTP Client to connect to AWS S3 for file transfer. Will I have to install SSH/Putty or anything else specially to connect ? I will be having the required PEM files and password predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between FTP and SFTP in the context of your question.

FTP and SFTP are protocols. Things like dependencies are only relevant to particular implementation of the protocol – FTP/SFTP library you will be using.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP is supported under Windows:

- either via a stand-alone tool like Putty,
- or by using a SFTP Client library in Delphi.

The only library I used was https://www.devart.com/sbridge. It worked somewhat for TLS/HTTPS. I had to rewrite the HTTPS client since the included component was not able to keep alive a HTTP1/1 connection... and it was very slow, so I rewrite their crypto core to use our SynCrypto unit. So perhaps their SFTP client "works" but is not very stable... You may try it!

I would go into calling `sftp.exe` from Putty project, which is just small, efficient and very stable.